# Changes in the form not sent to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-binding

I'm trying to send back the contents of the input field as follows.

```
@model Bike
@using (Html.BeginForm("BikeStore", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <input type="text" value="@Model.Color" />

  <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Bikes", "Home")
}
```

The action and the model are declared as follows.

```
public ActionResult BikeStore(Bike bike)
{
  ...
  return RedirectToAction("Bikes");
}

public partial class Bike
{
  [Key] public Guid Id{get; set;}
  [Required, StringLength(999)] public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

I'm hitting the breakpoint in the method `BikeStore` but `bike` passed in is empty, i.e. it's not null but all the strings are, the guids are 00..00 etc.

I've tried different variable types. I also tested `FormMethod.Get` and (not at the same time, of course) adding `HttpPost` attribute. No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net MVC binder system uses the name of the input elements to bind to the appropriate property or parameter. So, change this line:

```
 <input type="text" value="@Model.Color" />
```

to:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Color)
```

This will generate following html(for example):

```
 <input type="text" id="Color" name="Color" value="Black" />
```

Keep in mind that, you can use another helper which offers you to hard-type the name of the value:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor("Color")
```

Or, you can write plain html as you did and add name attribute, but let Asp.Net decide what must be the name of the element.

```
<input type = "text" 
    name = "@Html.NameFor(m => m.Color)"
    value = "@Model.Color" />
```

If we want to summarize the result of the answer, then let's write Pros and Cons of each version:

- Strongly typed version - These helpers can be used only with strongly typed views. The HTML generated by these helpers is not any different, but we use the strongly typed helper methods in our projects because they reduce the chances of causing an error by mistyping a property name.
- Hard-typed version - The string argument is used to search the `ViewData`, `ViewBag`, and view model to find a corresponding data item that can beused as the basic for the input element. So, for example, if you call 
  `@Html.TextBox("DataValue")`, the MVC Framework tries to find some item of data that corresponds with the key `DataValue`. The following locations are checked: `ViewBag.DataValue` and `Model.DataValue`.
  The first value that is found is used to set the value attribute of the generated HTML. (The last check, for `@Model.DataValue`, works only if the view model for the view contains a property or field called `DataValue`.) 
  If we specify a string like `DataValue.First.Name`, the search becomes more complicated. The MVC Framework will try different arrangements of the dot-separated elements, such as the following:

> ```
> •  ViewBag.DataValue.First.Name
> •  ViewBag.DataValue["First"].Name
> •  ViewBag.DataValue["First.Name"]
> •  ViewBag.DataValue["First"]["Name"]
> ```

Also keep in mind that, the first value that is found will be used, terminating 
the search.

Comment: It starts to be very clear now. Just a quicky. It all behaves as you say (yey!) except for one thing. I tried `@Html.DisplayFor(bike => bike.Id)` and it sure displays the guid but it's not returned in the controller (although I've put it inside the form). Am I using wrong helper? I want the guid to be displayed as a label, not changeable, but returned with the rest of editable fields. What should I use?

Comment: @AndyJ `DisplayFor` is intended only to display values and not return them to the controller. If you want to display the value as not changeable, then you have two options. 1. Use 'HiddenFor' helper method alongside with `DisplayFor`. Then, it will display the value in the label and will post it back to the action method. But, don't forget to secure hidden values in the future! Because, somebody can change the hidden value. 2. Add `readonly` attribute to your `TextBoxFor` method.